# I can't find Strapi nested components in my GraphQL query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, strapi

I'm very new to Strapi and GraphQL. I have created a nested data structure in Strapi that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk8L0.png) (this is a Navbar component). But when I go to GraphQL, my query looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIDLr.png).

So if this is the query:

```
query MyQuery {
  allStrapiNavbar {
    nodes {
      Category {
        Name
        children {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allStrapiNavbar": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "Category": [
            {
              "Name": "Community",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Name": "Modules",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Name": "Company",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Name": "Pricing",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

This means the data is being fetched correctly. However, I can't find the nested component 'Item' inside 'Category'.

This is what my gatsby-config.ts file looks like currently:

```
{
    resolve: "gatsby-source-strapi",
    options: {
      apiURL: process.env.STRAPI_API_URL || "http://localhost:1337",
      queryLimit: 1000, // Default to 100
      accessToken: process.env.STRAPI_TOKEN,
      collectionTypes:[ 'faq', 'doc', 'docCategory', 'faqCategory', 'release', 'userType' ],
      // contentTypes: [ 'Faq' ],
      singleTypes: [ 'navbar' ],
    },
```

I don't know why the data isn't showing up in GraphQL. I looked inside the children for Category, but the reality is that it should be at the same level as Name, which shows up.
Do I need to modify the gatsby-config file, or am I missing something else?

Edit: I am using the gatsby-source-strapi plugin.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this issue? I'm running into the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Doubly Nested Components are not allowed by Strapi. At least it used to be the case a few months ago (first half of 2023). But if you have managed to "hack" the .json file and allow that, then: you forgot items inside the GraphQL query.